# Parabolic Partial Diff Equation ( Heat Equation )

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, parabolic-pde

Im having a really hard time with this question, I honestly don't even know how to start this...can anyone help me?

We are in the Parabolic section of PDE, and we are asked to find the unique solution of the following PDE (looks non-homogenous)

Problem:
Let $\Omega$ be a bounded, normal domain in Rn. Assume a solution
exists to the following PDE in some space. Prove the solution is unique, and State the conditions you need on the solutions in order to conclude uniqueness.

## 1: (Heat Equation w/ damping)

\begin{align}
u_t = \nabla^2 u − u + F(x,t) \qquad & x \in \Omega, t > 0 \\
(∇u) \cdot \mathbf n = 0 \qquad & x\in \partial \Omega, t > 0 \\
u(x, 0) = f(x) \qquad  & x \in \Omega
\end{align}

Comment: Maybe you can try to take two solutions $u_1$ and $u_2$ and observe that their difference $w=u_1-u_2$ satisfies \begin{align}
w_t = \nabla^2 w − w \qquad & \mathbf x \in \Omega, t > 0 \\
(\nabla w) \cdot \mathbf n = 0 \qquad & \mathbf x\in \partial \Omega, t > 0 \\
w(\mathbf x,0) = 0 \qquad  & \mathbf x \in \Omega
\end{align} and then try to prove that $w$ must be identically zero

Comment: That looks familiar, how would I do that? Just integrating both sides???

Comment: You can solve the system in $w$ using separation of variables. The condition $w(\vec{x},0) = 0$ will enforce all coefficients of your Fourier series to be $0$ and hence your series solution will be $\equiv 0$.